# Problem with orthogonal mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

We have an orthogonal mapping  $A$ on an Euclidean space  and two linearly independent vectors $x,y$ such that for some $a,b\in \mathbb R$, $b\neq 0$,
$$
Ax=ax-by;
$$
$$
Ay=bx+ay.
$$ 
Since $x,y$ form a basis in $span [x,y]$ and $A$ is orthogonal,  $a^2+b^2=1$.

Are $x,y$ of the same norm? If not  how to obtain unit orthogonal  vectors $x',y'$, from $x,y$, such that  $Ax'=ax'-by',
Ay'=bx'+ay'$?

Comment: What's the definition of an orthogonal mapping?

Comment: $A:X\rightarrow X$ is an orthogonal mapping  iff $<Ax,Ay>=<x,y> $ for all $x,y \in X$.